# How to extract data from Bluetooth packet data?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wireshark

After capturing data from Android 5.0 Bluetooth HCI Snoop Log (Settings > Developer options > Bluetooth HCI Snoop Log), I acquired a lot Bluetooth package data with `ATT`, `HCI_CMD`, `HCI_EVT` protocols.

The Wireshark-compatible log can be downloaded [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/hxsdhl). How can I extract plain text data from the packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at that log, there's little if any "plain text data" in the log to extract!  It is, not surprisingly, mostly binary-encoded packet data.

The only way you'll get "plain text" out of it is if you ask Wireshark to export the packet dissections as text, so that the "plain text" you see is the text that shows up in the packet detail pane in Wireshark.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but which protocol packets should I look into? there are quite a lot packets, but I'm not sure which is useful, and which is solely for handshake / communication purpose.

Comment: Try a Web search for "bluetooth tutorial" and read those; they may help you understand what's going on in a Bluetooth log.

Comment: I will try my best then

Answer (score 1):

The data you are interested in is probably in the ATT-packets. These have a "Value" field, which usually is a string of hexadecimal numbers.

You can't just extract data from these values; there won't likely be a situation where exporting it to text would result in you seeing things like "hello world, some data, some more data".

You need to know what service the device is offering first, I suggest you look up the Bluetooth LE specifications on the official website. It could even be that the service used by your device isn't listed there. When you know the service, you can look into its attributes and start "decoding" your received values.